# Mysql Load Data: SET IF for all or given subset of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, set, load-data-infile

Got working import code for csv files into my 8-column database here:

```
Load Data LOCAL InFile 'file.csv' into table myTable
Fields Terminated by ',' 
OPTIONALLY Enclosed by '"'
Lines Terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 Lines
(col1, col2, @var3, @var4, col5, col6, col7, col8)
Set 
col3 = if(@var3 = '', NULL, @var3),
col4 = if(@var4 = '', NULL, @var4)
;
```

It's working fine in changing empty entries to NULL values, but....
Is there any way to shorten the Set part so I don't have to specify a condition for each and every column?
I actually need this for 7 of the 8 columns above, and this particular table is rather small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > Is there any way to shorten the Set part

   Yes, MySQL provides a shorthand function [`NULLIF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

   ```
   col3 = NULLIF(@var3, '') -- etc
   ```
2. > so I don't have to specify a condition for each and every column?

   Sadly not, although it should be fairly trivial to generate the desired SQL dynamically in your application code.

Comment: Oh well~

Thanks for the shorthand though!